# Games based on Eclipse Phase's world and/or system

Tags: eclipse-phase

**Are there any** well developed, relatively successful, and - in your own experience - well playable, unofficial (and Creative Commons licensed) **RPGs based on Eclipse Phase**'s world and/or system, as of today**?**

The authors of EP have voiced their hope - more than [once](http://www.eclipsephase.com/religion-and-nations-ep) - to see such games. I wonder if anyone has taken advantage of the opportunity yet. (I think the game mechanics would lend themselves quite well to unofficial adaptations of various SF movies and computer games.)

Comment: I have heard of several MHR-hacks in progress, but nothing as developed as what you are looking for.

Comment: I closes thing I know of is this: http://forum.rpg.net/showthread.php?521479-A-Strangely-Eclipsed-Aeon-Eclipse-Phase-Hack-for-Cthulhutech

Comment: You *might* get more answers if you relax your conditions for the games.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Eclipse Phase Resources page](http://eclipsephase.com/resources#homebrew) lists several rules conversions, though none of them has shown up with any regularity in the official Eclipse Phase forum.

Comment: This is a very good starting point, thank you. :) Considering the unfortunate lack of interest in this Q, I'm accepting this answer. If anyone comes up with a way better answer in the future, I might award them a bounty (in case I'll still be interested in the topic.)

Comment: Thanks. I think the key is not lack of interest in the question. It's just that you're asking for something "well developed, relatively successful, and - in your own experience - well playable," that doesn't yet seem to exist. I just received the new Fate-based Nova Praxis, which uses a somewhat similar setting. You might find that worth exploring.

Comment: I guess you're right. I'll get back to this later then. And I'll definitely take a look at Nova Praxis. Thank you.